# How to add all input values using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the dynamically generated input values in my project. I need to get all the values which has similar id's like "`test_1`".

```
<input type="hidden" id="test_1" value="1">
....
<input type="hidden" id="test_10" value="10">
```

So here i can use `$("input[id^='test_']")` to find all input values. IS there any logic to ADD all input values which has id "test_" ?

Comment: Where do you want to add these input values to?

Comment: I want all input values to be added and stores in another hidden fields for further use

Comment: Do you want to summarize the values or just concatenate?

Comment: @KARASZI I want to sum all input values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean get the sum of the input values that start test_ then try this

```
 val = 0;
 $("input[id^='test_']").each(function() {      
    val = $(this).attr('value') + val;
 });

 console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addValues(){
    var v = 0;
    $("input[id^='test_']").each(function(i, el){
        v += parseInt(el.value, 10);
    });
    return v;
}

var val_sum = addValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do it:

```
$("input#all").val($.map($("input[id^='test_']"), function( item ) {
  return $(item).val();
}).join(","));
```

With this the `<input id="all" type="hidden"/>` item will have all the values separated by `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3AW7j/) (http://jsfiddle.net/3AW7j/) code will help